# Make (Integromat) - Can't retrieve Facebook Pages that are tied to a Facebook Business Account

Tags: facebook, make.com, integromat-apps

I want to use some of my Facebook Pages into a Make integration, but Pages that are linked to my Facebook Business Account are not showing up.

Note that Facebook Pages that are linked to my personal account show up perfectly fine, but not the ones that have been created under my Business Account.

Anyone else having this issue lately?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

I was having this issue and stumbled upon a fix.

In my scenario, I tried to include an action to use Instagram Business, once I did that, it asked me to give additional permissions for my FB connection.

Once I completed that step, I tried the Facebook Pages action section again and suddenly I saw all my Facebook Business pages showing up.